# Arcgis get parameter value and edit in JS before append to html

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using ArcGIS javascript to pass some value from map service to front-end HTML.

I use `${parameter_name}` syntax and pass it into HTML by

```
var html = [];
html.push('<div>Parameter value is ${parameter_name}</div>');
InfoTemplate.setContent(html);
```

So that my HTML page will show an InfoTemplate holding

```
 Parameter value is XXX
```

But now I want to get the value `XXX` and edit it before push it into `html`. How should I get the value in my javascript?

Comment: You should tell us what version of the API you are using because the answer may differ from one version to another.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Sorry for missing info. I'm using arcgis js 3.21

Comment: According to the doc, my answer below should works in v3.26 (probably 3.21 too) see: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function in the parametrized template like this below:

```
myEditFunction = function(parameterValue) {
    //here you can edit the value before returning it
    return parameterValue;
}

var html = [];
html.push('<div>Parameter value is ${parameter_name:myEditFunction}</div>');
InfoTemplate.setContent(html);
```

See the documentation vor API v3.26: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.html especially the *Using custom functions* section.

Comment: I should thank you first! this is a new syntax for me. But I didn't suceed with arcgis js 3.21. Should I use later version?

Comment: According to the doc, my answer above should works in v3.26 (probably 3.21 too) see: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.html, what error do you get with this answer?

Comment: Try my edited answer. I removed `var` before `myEditFunction` to make the function global